# /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/4.6.4/libgcc.a warning

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, darwin, libgcc

I have a warning involving /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/4.6.4/libgcc.a. I was trying to compile a C++ project using a Makefile, which shows the following:

```
executeit: bplustree.o nonleafnode.o leafnode.o
    g++ -o executeit bplustree.o nonleafnode.o leafnode.o
bplustree.o: bplustree.cpp
    g++ -g -c bplustree.cpp
nonleafnode.o: nonleafnode.h nonleafnode.cpp
    g++ -g -c nonleafnode.h nonleafnode.cpp
leafnode.o: leafnode.h leafnode.cpp
    g++ -g -c leafnode.h leafnode.cpp
clean:
    rm executeit bplustree.o nonleafnode.o leafnode.o
```

When I invoke "make", I get the following output in Terminal:

```
g++ -g -c bplustree.cpp
g++ -g -c nonleafnode.h nonleafnode.cpp
g++ -g -c leafnode.h leafnode.cpp
g++ -o executeit bplustree.o nonleafnode.o leafnode.o
ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/4.6.4/libgcc.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

As you can see, I have gcc version 4.6.4. I am not sure if this warning is a threat to the project working in any way, but I would like to know what this warning means and if it is a threat. It would be nice if I can do something to remove it, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Mac OS X Version 10.6.8. The file /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/4.6.4/libgcc.a has "10.8.0", and this version of gcc I installed must have screwed me over. I don't know if I can remove this warning by installing OS X 10.8.0, but I will consider this question answered for now. Thank you.